# Rephrasing "which is nothing but"

Tags: mathematics, academic-writing

Is there a better way to rephrase the following sentence in math writing to be more suitable and professional for an academic paper.

> ... and C=[x1 , x2 , x3] is the optimal interval which is nothing but C.

Comment: It would be better to show the whole sentence, or even the paragraph. You might consider "which is exactly", but it's hard to tell from the fragment above whether it fits or not.

Answer (score 1):

Usually in math, an interval marked with square brackets is the set of points which lie between two points and include the two end points. So I am not sure what C = [x_1, x_2, x_3] is supposed to represent. Do you mean that C is a set of three points? Or are you trying to say that C is the union of two possibly disjoint intervals. Well, that is your problem; I probably would not be able to figure out what you intend in an article accepted by a mathematical journal.

There is nothing wrong with the locution “nothing but,” but if you mean “mathematically equivalent” in a paper on mathematics, I’d strongly be tempted to go with the phrase that means exactly what you mean.

It is very difficult to answer a question about only a partial sentence or even a question about a full sentence given with no context whatsoever. Consequently, I apologize if my answer is not what you need.